# What will happen when we cool the permanent magnet?

Tags: electromagnetism, superconductivity

When we are cooling the permanent magnet what property of magnet changes?
normally the superconductivity of magnets occurs at critical temperature(negative degrees).It is having a long life period and it exhibits huge magnetic field.
if we keep the magnets at some temperature which is nearer to critical temperature can we get any properties of that superconducting magnet

Is temperature inversely proportional to the magnetic field, magnetic flux density?

Comment: See [this](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=wKj0OfeZl0A) youtube video, either the (magnet) or the block of material below seems to be affected by being cooled.

Answer (score 1):

No.  You do not get more or less magnetism by cooling a permanent magnet made out of ferromagnetic material.

You are thinking of superconduction in some materials at certain (low) temperatures.  This phenomenon affects resistivity of the material, and has nothing to do directly with magnetism.  The zero resistivity can be exploited to set up a never-ending current which can produce an electromagnet.